# How was DCI Ian Reed involved in the kidnapping?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, luther

It's clear that DCI Reed is somehow involved in the kidnapping of the married couple at the beginning of *Luther* Season 1 Episode 5, however it's never clearly stated what role he partook in what was going on.

How was DCI Ian Reed tied to the kidnapping?  Why did he feel the need to clean up the mess?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from a [Wikia](http://luther.wikia.com/wiki/Ian_Reed)

> In Episode 5, he [Ian Reed] lets a robbery go ahead involving the Carrodus diamonds **in return for a cash payment**. However the Carrodus' are kidnapped by a rogue gang of American loansharks who kill the wife and one of their own members who tried to set her free. It turns out the [killed] gang member **was the nephew of Ian's gangland contact**, Bill whom Ian killed to protect his identity.

So it would appear that Reed was corrupt and influenced by his gangland contacts who were taking revenge for the killing of a family member.